# TurtleBot bringup error - "Robot not connected"

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-groovy, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the Bringup Tutorial for Turtlebot
Groovy. But I always get

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1368713745.246504] Create : robot not connected yet, sci not available
```

I have recently upgraded ROS to Groovy and I'm using a Gateway computer for Turtlebot.
I have done all the tutorials for Installation and Network Setup. The Turtlebot is plugged in and the lights are on.

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1368713742.227517] Create : robot not connected yet, sci not available
    [WARN] [WallTime: 1368713744.380423] Battery : unable to check laptop battery info [/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0 does not exist]
    [WARN] [WallTime: 1368713744.388681] Battery : unable to check laptop battery state [/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0 does not exist]
    [WARN] [WallTime: 1368713745.246504] Create : robot not connected yet, sci not available
    [turtlebot_laptop_battery-10] process has finished cleanly
    log file: /home/turtle2/.ros/log/07609262-be33-11e2-8571-d0df9aaae785/turtlebot_laptop_battery-10*.log
    [kinect_breaker_enabler-6] process has finished cleanly
    log file: /home/turtle2/.ros/log/07609262-be33-11e2-8571-d0df9aaae785/kinect_breaker_enabler-6*.log
```

At this point, the Base beeps and goes off. The iRobot light keeps on.
Then I turn the base back on:

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1368713868.243731] Failed to read sensor package. 5 retries left.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1368713868.498948] Failed to contact device with error: [Distance, angle displacement too big, invalid readings from robot. Distance: 29.73, Angle: 58.26]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1368713878.887388] Failed to contact device with error: [Error reading from SCI port. No data.]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62893/turtlebot-bringup-error---%22robot-not-connected%22/) by [larimanfrinato](https://answers.ros.org/users/4910/larimanfrinato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-10**:
I have the same problem and I'm very confused because it wasn't happening before.

**Comment by [aguadopd](https://answers.ros.org/users/6283/aguadopd/) on 2013-09-05**:
Same problem here. But cannot fix it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I modified minimal.launch and I don't seem to get the error anymore (after 5 minutes, so I'm not sure that's the fix, but hopefully it is). So I changed robot/name for robot_name and robot/type for robot_type.

Nevermind... it occurred again, but I fixed it by recharging the battery. I think it was almost empty, even though the dashboard was indicating that it was full and despite the fact that I had let the robot charge for a very long time.

---

Originally posted by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) with karma: 343 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2